# Calling another class` member functions via smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

In a program I'm writing I have a class that creates and handles some threads. After construction, an instance of this will be given an object of another class that the threads will be able to call member functions of.

I've gotten this to work with raw pointers (just replace the smart pointers), but since I have access to smart pointers, I tried to use them instead. Although without much progress .

Some searching led me to use `shared_ptr`s, so here's what I'm trying to do:

`Obj.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

#include "Caller.hpp"

class Caller;

class Obj : std::enable_shared_from_this<Obj> {
public:
    Obj(Caller &c);

    void dothing();
};
```

`Caller.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

#include "Obj.hpp"

class Obj;

class Caller {
public:
    void set_obj(std::shared_ptr<Obj> o);

    std::shared_ptr<Obj> o;
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include "Caller.hpp"
#include "Obj.hpp"

void Caller::set_obj(std::shared_ptr<Obj> o)
{
    this->o = o;
}

Obj::Obj(Caller &c)
{
    c.set_obj(shared_from_this());
}

void Obj::dothing()
{
    std::cout << "Success!\n";
}

int main()
{
    Caller c;
    auto obj = std::make_shared<Obj>(c);

    c.o->dothing();
}
```

Running this code leads to a throw of `std::bad_weak_ptr`, but I don't understand why. Since `obj` is a `shared_ptr`, shouldn't the call to `shared_from_this()` be valid?

Compiled with `g++ main.cpp` with `gcc 7.1.1`.

Comment: Feel free to rephrase the title question. There are many other questions that matches, but I have no idea what else to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shared_from_this` only works *after you are wrapped in a shared pointer*.

At the point of construction, there is no shared pointer to you yet.  So you cannot `shared_from_this` until after your constructor is finished.

A way around this is the old "virtual constructor" trick.<sup>1</sup>

```
class Obj : std::enable_shared_from_this<Obj> {
  struct token {private: token(int){} friend class Obj;};
public:
  static std::shared_ptr<Obj> create( Caller& c );
  Obj(token) {}
};

inline std::shared_ptr<Obj> Obj::create( Caller& c ) {
  auto r = std::make_shared<Obj>(token{0});
  c.set_obj(r);
  return r;
}
```

then in the test code:

```
Caller c;
auto obj = Obj::create(c);

c.o->dothing();
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71073a2230cda5b7).

---

<sup>1</sup> virtual constructors are neither virtual nor constructors.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But did you mean to have the constructor private? `g++` wont compile it, dumping a lot of errors ending with "[constructor] declared private here.

Comment: @tmp fixed, now with token security.

Comment: It's called factory pattern.

Comment: @Tmplt Sorry, final typo fixed.